# Average distance of a freefalling body in random intervals

Tags: probability, physics, expected-value

This is taken from the first example in Griffith's intro to QM:

---

Suppose I drop a rock off a cliff of height *h*. As it falls, I snap a million photographs, at random intervals. On each picture I measure the distance the rock has fallen. *Question*: What is the *average* of all these distances? That is to say, what is the *time average* of the distance traveled?

**Solution**: The rock starts out at rest, and picks up speed as it falls; it spends more time near the top, so the average distance must be less than *h/2*.  Ignoring air resistance, the distance *x* at time *t* is

$$ x(t) = \frac 1 2 gt^2 $$

The velocity is $dx/dt = gt$, and the total flight time is $T = \sqrt{2h/g}$.  The probability that the camera flashes in the interval *dt* is *dt/T*, so the probability that a given photograph shows a distance in the corresponding range *dx* is

$$ \frac{dt}{T} = \frac{dx}{gt}\sqrt{\frac{g}{2h}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{hx}} dx $$.

---

The solution goes on from there, but there are some things that kind of seem ambiguous about the description here.  I could ask a ton of questions about exactly what scenario is being described.  But rather than try to ask all these questions, I feel like I might understand things better if I try to think about it in more standard probability language.

In other probabilistic analyses, we need: (1) events, (2) their probabilities, and (3) an associated value. Then we can apply the expected value formula.

So what *exactly* is the event that we're talking about here?  I grab a random time $t_a$ and a moment soon after $t_a+\varepsilon$, and I grab a random photograph, and find the probability that the duration when the camera shutter was open lies entirely inside of $[t_a,t_a+\varepsilon]$?

So maybe we can model it by first fixing some small $\varepsilon>0$ and using a uniform pdf over the interval $[0,T-\varepsilon]$.  There's our events and the associated probabilities.

Now what's the associated values?  The length of the rock's path through this interval?  If that's right then it's precisely $\frac 1 2 g(t_a+\varepsilon)^2 - \frac 1 2 gt_a^2 = gt_a\varepsilon + g\varepsilon^2/2$.

Now we apply the expected value formula and get

$$\int_0^{T-\varepsilon}(gt_a\varepsilon + g\varepsilon^2/2)\frac{1}{T-\varepsilon}dt_a$$

But at this point it looks like something went wrong.  If you compute the integral and take the limit as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ you get nonsense.  And at the very least I'm not getting the answer Griffiths does.

I don't think I got my events wrong, or their probabilities, although maybe I did.  More likely I think I got the associated values wrong.  But if it's not the distance the rock goes through from time $t_a$ to $t_a+\varepsilon$ then what is it?

---

Note that I saw this but it didn't clarify anything for me: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/195202/probability-density-of-a-freely-falling-body

---

[Edit: As I think more about my analysis, it probably has something to do with the relationship between $t_a$ and $\varepsilon$.  In fact I'm realizing it doesn't make sense to integrate with respect to $t_a$ since that is explicitly a single point ... I think ... right?  But then I'm not sure how to properly set up the integral.

Sorry, I've never been very good at modeling physical systems with infinitesimals.  The approximations always confuse me.]

Comment: More generally, by the way, we have the set of *outcomes* $[0, h]$, which are the different heights that the rock can have fallen; the set of *events*, which are each a set of possible outcomes; and we have a probability measure that assigns each event a probability.  For example, the interval $[0, h/4]$ has probability measure $1/2$, as does the interval $[h/4, h]$, while the interval $[0, h/2]$ has probability $\sqrt{2}/2$, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a fixed $\epsilon>0$, you can take the limit through now and end up with the infinitesimal $\mathrm{d}x(t)=gt\,\mathrm{d}t$ as a differential form.

This is actually the infinitesimal you need to integrate with (more fundamentally, you're pulling out FTC here on $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$). The problem with your other formulation is that you already have an $\epsilon$, then you tried to integrate again wrt $\mathrm{d}t_a$, causing the zero.

What you would need is to also normalize by dividing through by $\epsilon$ to account for the fact that the interval of shutter-length is itself decreasing. Once you do so you'll recover the result as a derivative, the total distance seen *per shutter time*.